# Using startsWith Method

Tags: trigger, community

I have a method has list of string which is called getMapField:

```
public static Map<String,String> getMapField(){

    Map<String,String> tmp = new Map<String,String>();
    //From SchoolSnapshot to Account
    tmp.put('Address_Street__c','BillingStreet');
    tmp.put('Address_City__c','BillingCity');
    tmp.put('Address_Country__c','BillingCountry');
    tmp.put('Address_State_Province__c','BillingState');
    tmp.put('Address_Zip_Postal_Code__c','BillingPostalCode');
      tmp.put('Phone__c','Phone');
    tmp.put('Phone','Phone__c');


    //From Account to SchoolSnapshot
    tmp.put('BillingStreet','Address_Street__c');
    tmp.put('BillingCity','Address_City__c');
    tmp.put('BillingCountry','Address_Country__c');
    tmp.put('BillingState','Address_State_Province__c');
    tmp.put('BillingPostalCode','Address_Zip_Postal_Code__c');


    return tmp;
}
```

This method called under another method which is:

```
public static List<String> getFieldName() {

    List<String> tmp = new List<String>();
    Map<String,String> mapField = getMapField();
    System.debug('>>>mapField: ' + mapField);

    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> customObjMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('customObj__c'.toLowerCase()).getDescribe().Fields.getMap();
    //Get all field name from customObj__c sObject
    if ( customObjMap != null ) {
        for ( Schema.SObjectField ft : customObjMap.values() ) {
            String f = ft.getDescribe().getName();
            Integer len = f.length() - 3;

            if ( f.indexOf('__c') == len && !customObjService.FIELD_NOT_MAPPED_TO_ACCOUNT.contains(f) ) {
                tmp.add((f.startsWith('Address'))?mapField.get(f):f);
                system.debug('tmp >>>' + tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    //system.debug('tmp >>>' + tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

I would like to change this code under method getFieldName :

```
tmp.add((f.startsWith('Address'))?mapField.get(f):f);
```

at the moment tmp not found all string from the getMapField only selects the prefix of Address.

I want to get all including Address prefix.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more detail what is datatype of mapField and tmp.

Comment: please refer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107441/replicate-account-record

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the problem by using Ternary operator.

Thanks